# Clickable table rows using jquery select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make clickable table rows work with the jquery selectable function, but I'm running into difficulties. It works great with li elements, but as soon as I try to use a table, the click event quits working. Drag to select works, but I really need to be able to click as well. Here is my code:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#selectable").selectable();
});
```

```css
#feedback {
  font-size: 1.4em;
}
#selectable .ui-selecting {
  background: #FECA40;
}
#selectable .ui-selected {
  background: #F39814;
  color: white;
}
#selectable {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
#selectable tr {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0.4em;
  font-size: 1em;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css"> -->

<table id="selectable" style="width:100%">
  <tr class="ui-widget-content">
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="ui-widget-content">
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Does anyone know how to get click or ctrl + click working in the above example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a `filter` to the `selectable()`.

Please see the documentation for [filter](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/#option-filter).

I have updated your example, it's just a small change:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#selectable").selectable({filter: 'tr'});
});
```

```css
#feedback {
  font-size: 1.4em;
}
#selectable .ui-selecting {
  background: #FECA40;
}
#selectable .ui-selected {
  background: #F39814;
  color: white;
}
#selectable {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
#selectable tr {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0.4em;
  font-size: 1em;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css"> -->

<table id="selectable" style="width:100%">
  <tr class="ui-widget-content">
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="ui-widget-content">
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: this is not answering the OP question. It's just a bunch of code, please add some explanation on how this addresses OP concerns, what problem there was, and how you solved it.

Comment: @PA. it's not a "bunch of code", it's one small change, namely `{filter: 'tr'}` in order to make rows selectable. It solves OP's question completely.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts to be fair, PR posted this before I added the three lines above the code.

Comment: @mpf82 I looked at the edit history -- your initial answer was perfectly sufficient imo. +1

Comment: Both this answer and the one below were correct, the filter did indeed get this working. I guess it's only fair to give it to the first response.

Answer (score 1):

use a filter for your case. 
http://api.jquery.com/filter/

```js
$(function() {
  $("#selectable").selectable({filter: 'tr'});
});
```

```css
#feedback {
  font-size: 1.4em;
}
#selectable .ui-selecting {
  background: #FECA40;
}
#selectable .ui-selected {
  background: #F39814;
  color: white;
}
#selectable {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
#selectable tr {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0.4em;
  font-size: 1em;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css"> -->

<table id="selectable" style="width:100%">
  <tr class="ui-widget-content">
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="ui-widget-content">
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```